# What is the meaning of creating a reference out of a temporary in rust?

Tags: rust

Code:

```
fn main() {
    let r0 = &mut String::from("my string");
    *r0 = String::from("new string");
    println!("{r0}");
}
```

Output:

```
new string
```

- Given the above code snippet, where exactly does the referred entity by reference `r0` get stored and what is its lifetime?
- And why is this allowed in rust?
- What is this feature called?
- What are the use cases for this feature?

Comment: The use case is being able to easily create a reference to a freshly created value to pass to code that insists on receiving a _reference_. For example, if a function takes `sink: &mut impl Write`, you can pass it `&mut io::stdout().lock()`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a4232859150f11b41bb453c2d2cadc29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given the above code snippet, where exactly does the referred entity by reference `r0` get stored and what is its lifetime?

It is stored in a variable the compiler declares implicitly (a *temporary*), and it lasts until the end of the scope.

> And why is this allowed in rust?

Temporaries are always created for values that are not stored in variables and references are taken to them. Usually, the temporary lives until the end of the statement. However, when the temporary is part of a `let` statement, it is subject to [temporary lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension), that extends its lifetime until the end of the scope.

> What is this feature called?

As I said, "temporary lifetime extension".

> What are the use cases for this feature?

This is nothing that you couldn't do by yourself, but it makes it easier to work in some cases: rather then declaring a variable manually when you need to pass it to some code that expects a reference, the compiler can do this for you.